# Laravel 5.5 retrieve first record within nested relationship

Tags: php, laravel, orm, relationship

How can I use the `first()` method on a relation in an Eloquent query builder?

I only want to return the first section and the first subsection within that section.

I have the following query in my Assessment service:

```
public function firstSubsection()
    {
        return $this->model->with(['sections.subsections' => function ($q) {
                $q->take(1);
        }])->first();
    }
```

This returns multiple sections:

```
 {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Assessment 1",
        "description": "<p>Some description</p>",
        "created_at": "2018-03-09 17:14:43",
        "updated_at": "2018-03-09 17:14:43",
        "sections": [
            {
                "id": 5,
                "name": "Section 1",
                "description": null,
                "parent": null,

                "created_at": "2018-03-09 17:14:52",
                "updated_at": "2018-03-09 17:14:52",
                "pivot": {
                    "assessment_id": 1,
                    "section_id": 5
                },
                "subsections": [
                    {
                        "id": 6,
                        "name": "Subsection 1",
                        "description": "<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet<br>\r\n</p>",
                        "parent": 5,
                        "position": 6,
                        "created_at": "2018-03-09 17:15:08",
                        "updated_at": "2018-03-21 11:40:10"
                    }
                ]
            },
        {
            "id": 10,
            "name": "Section 2",
            "description": null,
            "parent": null,
            "position": 10,
            "created_at": "2018-03-20 14:34:50",
            "updated_at": "2018-03-20 14:34:50",
            "pivot": {
                "assessment_id": 1,
                "section_id": 10
            },
            "subsections": []
        }
    ]
}
```

Any idea how I can achieve this?

I have the following relationships in my Eloquent models:

```
class Section extends Model
{
    use BelongsToSortedManyTrait, SortableTrait;

    public $fillable = [
        'id',
        'name',
        'description',
        'parent',
        'position'
    ];

    public static $rules = [
        // create rules
        'name' => 'required'
    ];

    public function assessments() {
        return $this->belongsToSortedMany('App\Models\Assessment');
    }

    public function subsections() {
        return $this->hasMany(self::class, 'parent')->sorted();
    }
}



class Assessment extends Model
{

    public $fillable = [
        'id',
        'name',
        'description'
    ];

    public static $rules = [
        // create rules
    ];

    public function sections()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Section')->whereNull('parent')->sorted();
    }


}
```

Comment: what do you want to achieve ?

Comment: @LeoinstanceofKelmendi Read the second line in the post.

Comment: ->get()->first();

Comment: @Indra That doesn't make any difference.

Comment: Try `public function firstSubsection()
    {
        return $this->model->with(['sections' => function ($q) {
                $q->first()->with(['subsections' => function ($q) {
                $q->first()}]);
        }])->first();
    }` [Not tested]

Comment: public function firstSubsection()
    {
        return $this->with('sections.subsections')->first();
    } // not tested

Comment: @ab_in That returns the first section but without the subsection.

Comment: @Indra That will only run the `first()` on the outer model. So it returns the first assessment with everything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the end I had to do it like this:

```
public function firstSubsection()
    {
        return $this->model->with(['sections' => function ($q) {
            $q->with(['subsections' => function ($q) {
                $q->first();
            }
            ])->first();
        }])->first();
    }
```

Thanks to @ab_in for leading me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure this will work or not, but you can try this logic:

If you want to eager load the first section and subsection of your model you should create a new relationship in your model :

```
public function firstSectionOnly()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Section::class)->orderBy('id', 'asc');
}
```

And in **Section** model define

```
public function firstSubSectionOnly()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Subsection::class)->orderBy('id', 'asc');
}
```

Then you can eager load it in your current model:

```
public function firstSubsection()
{
    return $this->model->with(['firstSectionOnly.firstSubSectionOnly'])->first();
}
```

After trying this. Tell me it is working or have errors.

Comment: This is for a JSON API so I can't use eager loading unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function firstSubsection()
{
    return $this->model->with(['sections.subsections' => function ($q) 
    {
            $q->take(1)->first();
    }])->first();
}
```

Comment: This still returns multiple sections.

Answer (score 0):

`Take(1)` and `first()` doing same thing right now. But still its not a problem. Remove `take(1)` and add `->get()` after `first()`

Give it a try.

Comment: It still returns multiple sections. It does return only one subsection however. But I need it to only return one section.